# Numbering pages and subsections

Tags: adobe-indesign

I've read through a few threads and tried section numbers, but can't work this out.

```
`Pg1 - cover
 Pg2 - contents
 Pg3 - section a cover
 Pg4 - section a 1 of 2
 Pg5 - section a 2 of 2
 Pg6 - section b cover
 Pg7 - section b 1 of 2
 Pg8 - section b 2 of 2
 Pg9 - cover`
```

I'm trying to get "1 of 2" etc generated automatically based on starting a new section, independent of page numbers.
Sections don't seem to do this, but I can't work out what will.

Any clues?

Answer (score 1):

Your section start will *define* the "1" of the "1 of X."

You use the placeholder marker to *give* you the "1."

The "X" itself is generated by a *text variable*:

[InDesign CS5: Placeholder for "number of pages in a document"?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/6821/indesign-cs5-placeholder-for-number-of-pages-in-a-document)

> If you go to Type > Text variables > Insert variable, you will find "Last page Number."

This gives you the last page number in the section, which is what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.
The problem is more that I cannot have both page numbers and section numbers, independent of each other.
So I would like each page numbered sequentially an _in addition_ have a section start it's own independent numbering.
That way a specific page could be "Page Number 34, Section D, Part 3 of 6" for example.

Comment: @SamThorne No, I don't think you can have two independent automatic page numbering variables with one being section-dependent and the other being document-dependent. Either a page is named 34 or it's named D-12, but the program can't label it both at once. One of those you have to type in manually.